# Get filename without extension within makefile

Tags: makefile

My **makefile** looks like this:

```
SRCS    = $(wildcard *.asm)
OBJS    = ${SRCS:.asm=.o}

# define a suffix rule for .asm -> .o
.asm.o : $(SRCS)
    nasm -f elf $<

all: $(OBJS)
    gcc -o ?? $<
           ^need the name of the target without file extension here ($* is blank)
```

However, `$*` is working within `.asm.o` but is blank within `all`.
How would I go about setting the gcc output filename to the filename of **the object file** without *any* extension?

For example, I want it to execute the following (after the *.o* file is generated by nasm)

```
gcc filename filename.o
```

Comment: The target in your example is "all". But you don't want "gcc all filename.o", do you?

Comment: @Sebastian No, I want `gcc filename filename.o`. Is it possible to have the target name to be dynamically defined, so that I can use `$@`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are looking for

```
.PHONY: all
all: $(patsubst %.o,%,$(OBJS))
%: %.o
    gcc -o $@ $<
```

Your attempt would define a target `all` which depended on all the object files as if it contained them all; I presume you really want each object file to be independent, and for the `all` target to depend on them all being made.

(Technically you could now use `$*` because it is identical to `$@` in this case, but that's just obscure.)

This is by and large isomorphic to your existing `nasm` rule, except when there is no suffix, you cannot use the suffix syntax. In other words, your rule is equivalent to

```
OBJS = $(patsubst %.asm,%.o,$(SRCS))
%.o: %.asm
    nasm -f elf $<
```

The only remaining difference is the `.PHONY` declaration which just documents that `all` isn't a file name.

Comment: To drop suffixes from a list you can also use the `basename` builtin: `all: $(basename $(OBJS))`.

Comment: The comment of ldelic implies that DarkCthulhu could as well write `gcc -o $(basename $<) $<` in his rule.

Comment: As an aside, Make already knows how to build an executable from an `*.o` file, so creating your own rule for this is redundant and somewhat likely to introduce unwanted behavior (by disabling a more-complex built-in rule).

Answer (score 10):

```
Use VAR = $(basename your_file.ext) <=> $(VAR) = your_file
```

Let's say that you want to remove `.o` from `test.o`

```
VAR = $(basename test.o)
```

resulting in `$VAR` containing "test"

[See More Functions Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html)